# Stuck on a term in $\operatorname{Var}\left[ \widehat{\beta}_0 \right]$ proof

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, least-squares, expected-value, independence

So I was trying to prove that $\operatorname{Var}[\hat{\beta}_0] = \dfrac{\sigma^2n^{-1} \sum{(x_i)^2}}{\sum{(x_i-\bar{x}})^2}$

And I got stuck with the part $\dfrac{-2\bar{x}}{\sum{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}} \sum[{(x_i - \bar{x})}E(u_i\bar{u})]$

Now, I need to show that this whole expression equals 0 but I don't know how to go about it. I'm mainly confused as to how I should be treating the $E(u_i\bar{u})$ term. I have read that $u_i$ and $u_j$ are uncorrelated so  $E(u_iu_j)=0$ so long as $i \ne j$. But I don't know how I can use that fact to reduce the $E(u_i\bar{u})$ part to something. The $u_i$ I'm assuming would go on forever i.e. $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ but the $\bar{u}$ would only have the values of $u$ that go from $1$ to $n$ like $u_1+u_2+\cdots+u_n$, so how should I go about this?

EDIT:

$u_i's$ are NOT the residual terms. These are the actual $u's$ from the line/function that models the relationship between $y$ and $x$ And $\bar{u}$ would be defined to be actual $u's$ from $1$ to $n$ whole divided by $n$

I hope I'm clear.

Can anyone help simplify this? Thank you.

Comment: You need to define the various terms in this. For example, I guess the $u_i$'s are residuals from a linear regression and the $x_i$'s are the design points, but it would be helpful if you could rewrite the question so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: Edited! Can you please check? Thanks.

Comment: See page 6 on https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese302/extra_mtls/Regression_Notes.pdf

Comment: Cross posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2954380/321264.